# event listener not responding even after getting called

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

the event listener used on my list container needs to respond on click and mark the list checked if i click on text and remove the list item if i click on span

```
`const InputBox = document.getElementById("input-box");
const ListContainer = document.getElementById("list-container");

function addTask(){
    if(InputBox.value ===''){
        alert("Text Cannot be Empty!");
    }
    else{
        let li= document.createElement("li");
        li.innerHTML = InputBox.value;
        ListContainer.appendChild(li);
        let span = document.createElement("span");
        span.innerHTML = ".\u00d7"
        li.appendChild(span);
    }
    InputBox.value = "";
}

InputBox.addEventListener("keypress", function (event) {
    if (event.key === "Enter") {
        event.preventDefault();
        addTask();
    }
});

ListContainer.addEventListener("click",function(e){
    if(e.target.tagname === "LI"){
        e.target.classList.toggle("checked");
    }
    else if(e.target.tagname === "SPAN"){
        e.target.parentElement.remove();
    }
},false);`
```

this is the code and my event listener on list container isnt working

Answer (score 0):

try to create the li element with or without the "checked" class and then check first that you add the "checked" class,
I have just created a new function which is

```
  function createListItem(text, isChecked){
    const listItem= document.createElement('li');
    listItem.textContent = text;
    if(isChecked){
        listItem.classList.add('checked');
    }
}
```

add this on your one and it will work.